# Finding number of solutions for a trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry

How can I find the number of solutions of this equation in interval $[0,\pi]$:
$$ 3x + \tan x = \frac{5\pi}{2}$$
I have no clue how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the answers is tricky, but we can see how many there are. The function 
$$f(x) = 3x + \tan x $$
increases monotonically from 0 to $\infty$ on the interval $[0, \pi/2)$, then again increases monotonically from $-\infty$ to $3\pi$ on the interval $(\pi/2, \pi]$. It must hit $5\pi/2$ exactly once in each interval, by the intermediate value theorem, so there are 2 solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your ability, plot $\tan x$ and $\frac{5 \pi}{2} - 3x$ on the same graph and look at the number of intersections.